# Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be a Borel regular measures in $\mathbb{R}^n$ show that $\mu + \nu$ is a Borel regular measure

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be a Borel regular measures in $\mathbb{R}^n$ show that $\mu + \nu$ is a Borel regular measure

Is easy to see that $\mu + \nu$ is a outer measure and using the Carathéodory criterion I show that the sum measure is a Borel measure, but I have problems with the regularity because by regularity of $\mu$ and $\nu$ given $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  exists $F_1 , F_2$ Borealian sets such that
$E \subset F_1, F_2$ and $\mu(E)= \mu(F_1)$, $\nu(E)=\nu(F_2)$ I try to use the Borealian $F_1 \cup F_2$ to show the regularity but I not sure how proceed.
Any hint or help I will be very grateful.

Comment: What is your definition of regularity?

Comment: $(\mu+\nu) (E)\geq (\mu+\nu) (F_1\cup F_2)=\mu (F_1\cup F_2)+\nu (F_1\cup F_2)\geq \mu(F_1)+\nu(F_2)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm my definition is: a outer measure $\mu$ is Borel regular if for any $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ exists a Borel set $F$ such that $\mu(E)=\mu(F)$ and $E \subset F$

Comment: In your answer I have one question, why $(\mu + \nu) (E) \geq (\mu + \nu )( F_1 \cup F_2)$